# Lodash sortBy sorts and splits between integers and floats

Tags: sorting, lodash

I'm using Lodash, trying to use sortBy.

For some reason, it sorts, but doesn't treat integers and floats equally.

I end up with this "sorted" result:

[image]

Displayed using Chart.js:

[image]

Why is this?
My code:

```js
output = _(dataSet)
  .sortBy(output, dimension)
  .groupBy(dimension)
  .map((objs, key) => ({
    dimension: key,
    measure: _.meanBy(objs, measure) }))
  .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_.groupBy()` method creates an object with the value of the property you've selected. Since `dimension` is a numeric property, they are traversed by the numeric value for integers, and as strings for floats (see this [article](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#integer-indices)).

The solution is to sort by the actual numeric value, after you convert the grouping object back to an array:

```
output = _(dataSet)
  .groupBy(dimension)
  .map((objs, key) => ({
    dimension: _.head(objs, 'dimension'),
    measure: _.meanBy(objs, measure) }))
  .sortBy(output, dimension) // <- sort here
  .value();
```

Comment: Hmm, I did try placing the sortBy at the end (and just tried again), but now it only sorts the integers, and doesn't seem to do anything to the floats / strings: https://imgur.com/a/XmOsr5B

Comment: Because you take `dimension` from the `key` it's a string, and now a number now. Take it from the 1st object in the group (like I did in the example), or parse it from the key.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here — I copied your code and got the same output, and tried ``dimension: parseFloat(key),`` but it still didn't sort it correctly

Comment: I can just use ``output.sort((a, b) => (a.dimension > b.dimension) ? 1 : -1)`` after this and it sorts it correctly — but still not sure where I'm going wrong with Lodash.

Comment: Update your answer with some sample data, and expected results, so I can actually see how my code interacts with your data.